# Cufonfonts vs Typography clouds

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, typography

I want to use Archer font family on one of my sites. When I try to find the the font I see following two options:

1. http://www.typography.com/fonts/archer/webfonts/
2. http://www.cufonfonts.com/en/font/13323/archer-book

Typography has pay per use plan under which I can directly use the font.

On the other hand cufonfonts.com lets me download the webfonts for the Archer font family and I can use them directly on my site using @font-face. It is also free.

So can any one tell me if there is something that I may have missed out with the CufonFonts. Is there any downside to using the CufonFonts or if it is not legal. I have tried to use the CufonFonts and it works fine. So can someone please suggest the right way.

Note: I cannot use any substitute font for the Archer. That is a hard requirement. So either I use the free Cufonfonts or I'll have to purchase the typography plan.

Answer (score 1):

The Cufon Fonts website declares the following in its [DMCA page](https://www.cufonfonts.com/dmca):

> “All fonts on cufonfonts.com are uploaded by designers and they certify that they are the legal owner or representative of the font they upload. Unfortunately we do not have the technology and manpower to check the commercial or legal aspect of every font that is uploaded.”

Therefore, they are not the creators of the fonts, and they have no opinion on the legal aspect of the files they provide. It's up to you to figure out what to do with them legally.

Only the copyright owner of a font can tell you how you can legitimately use it, whether on a website, in a printed document or even in a logo. This is usually described in a legal document called EULA (End-User License Agreement), which you will receive from the font creator.

If you want to avoid legal problems, the right way to download a font is to obtain it directly from the font designer or from the font foundry, which may involve paying for them.

Archer, for example, is a commercial font by [Hoefler and Co.](https://www.typography.com/faq#10), so if you download it from the Cufon Fonts website and use it directly in your work without paying for it, you are [violating the EULA](https://www.typography.com/policies/eula) of this font foundry.